# Getting Date Time in Unix Time as Byte Array which size is 8 bytes with Java

Tags: java, date, byte

I know I can get it in 4 bytes like so:

```
int unixTime = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
byte[] productionDate = new byte[]{
        (byte) (unixTime >> 24),
        (byte) (unixTime >> 16),
        (byte) (unixTime >> 8),
        (byte) unixTime

};
```

but is there a way to get it in 8 bytes using shifts?

Comment: How long does this code have to work for?  For the next 18 years, "unix time" fits in 31 bits, i.e., 4 bytes signed.  So if you want it in 8 bytes, just add 4 bytes of zero on the left, i.e., most significant end.

Comment: @user13784117 Were you too young to learn anything at all from the [year 2000 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)?

Comment: Not at all. But I know the difference between code that will be around next year, and code that won't.  I suspect the OP's code is the latter: after all, it's a pretty elementary question.

Comment: If the code is for learning and learning is for life, then they will be learning exactly the wrong thing if applying your suggestion.@user13784117

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just read as a signed `long`.

```java
long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

byte[] bytes = new byte[] {
        (byte) (unixTime >> 56),
        (byte) (unixTime >> 48),
        (byte) (unixTime >> 40),
        (byte) (unixTime >> 32),        
        (byte) (unixTime >> 24),
        (byte) (unixTime >> 16),
        (byte) (unixTime >> 8),
        (byte) unixTime
};
```

Alternatively, using NIO ByteBuffer

```java
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES)
    .putLong(unixTime);

byte[] bytes = buffer.array();
```

Comment: woops idk how I forgot to do that.